# I used browser emulation mode in asp.net. I got an error like "flash movie not yet registered". how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webcam-capture, webcam.js

I used browser emulation mode in asp.net. I got an error like "flash movie not yet registered". But when I run the url in internet explorer is working well. I think the issue might be on browser emulation mode help me to fix this error.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
            var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("EditReceipt.aspx") %>';
            $(function () {
                jQuery("#webcam").webcam({
                    width: 320,
                    height: 240,
                    mode: "save",
                    swffile: '<%=ResolveUrl("Webcam_Plugin/jscam.swf") %>',
                    debug: function (type, status) {
                        $('#camStatus').append(type + ": " + status + '<br /><br />');
                    },
                    onSave: function (data) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: pageUrl + "/GetCapturedImage",
                            data: '',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (r) {
                                var myString = r;
                                var arr = myString.split('=');
                                var url = arr[0];
                                var side = arr[1];

                                switch (side) {
                                    case "Front":
                                        $("[id*=CapturedImage]").attr("src", url);
                                        $("[id*=Image1]").attr("src", url);
                                        $('#<%=FrontImage.ClientID%>').val(url);;
                                        break;
                                    case "Back":
                                        $("[id*=CapturedImage]").attr("src", url);
                                        $("[id*=Image2]").attr("src", url);
                                        $('#<%=BackImage.ClientID%>').val(url);;
                                        break;
                                }
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.d);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    onCapture: function () {
                        webcam.save(pageUrl);
                    }
                });
            });
            function Capture() {
                webcam.capture();
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Simple answer, don't use browser emulation. It's unreliable rubbish. Test in a real browser instance.

Comment: yeah! i know that Mr Rory McCrossan. but i need a solution for browser emulation